# Sklearn RandomForest: predict_proba: wrong shape and how to get rid of compliment probability

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

After training RForest on 6000 component vectors labeled into 9 classes I try to get class probabilities for previously unseen set of vectors shaped as:

```
X.shape
Out[6]: (15091, 6000)
```

with:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier( n_estimators = 100 )    
probs = clf.predict_proba(X)
```

As a result I get a list:

```
[array([[ 0.61,  0.39],
        [ 0.62,  0.38],
        [ 0.24,  0.76],
        ..., 
        [ 0.96,  0.04],
        [ 0.49,  0.51],
        [ 0.91,  0.09]]), array([[ 0.91,  0.09],
        [ 0.94,  0.06],
        [ 0.93,  0.07],
        ..., 
        [ 1.  ,  0.  ],
        [ 0.96,  0.04],
        [ 0.99,  0.01]]), array([[ 0.95,  0.05],
        [ 0.9 ,  0.1 ],
        [ 0.95,  0.05],
        ...,
```

with compliment probabilities. Is there any way to get rid of compliment probability in `predict_proba`, so the output of this method instead of `[ 0.96,  0.04]` contained just `0.96` without coding this out yourself?

*** Major Update ***

After converting list of probabilities returned by RForest in to numpy array:

```
predictions = np.array(probs)
```

Looking at its shape:

```
predictions.shape
(9, 15091, 2)
```

Reveals the main problem: I have 9 classes and 15091 samples, so `predict_proba` should return 15091 lists where each list contains in turn 9 lists of two probaility elements (compliments). Instead I get 9 lists, each 15091 elements long, where each element is a compliment probability list.

In short, why  instead of:

(15091, 9, 2)

I get:

(9, 15091, 2)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you can't do that out of the box, but why not just extend the class?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np

class RandomForestClassifier2(RandomForestClassifier):
    def predict_proba(self,X,drop_compliment=False):
        result = super().predict_proba(X)
        if drop_compliment:
            result = np.array([p for p,_ in result])
        return result
```

Example usage:

```
# Generate some dummy data
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)
clf = RandomForestClassifier2(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

to which you can get the "default" `RandomForestClassifier` result by:

```
clf.predict_proba(X,drop_compliment=False)

Out[13]:
array([[ 0.88724838,  0.11275162],
       [ 0.73563529,  0.26436471],
       [ 0.88724838,  0.11275162],
       ..., 
       [ 0.16937022,  0.83062978],
       [ 0.14297294,  0.85702706],
       [ 0.14297294,  0.85702706]])
```

or the output you want by:

```
clf.predict_proba(X,drop_compliment=True)

Out[14]:
array([ 0.88724838,  0.73563529,  0.88724838, ...
        0.16937022,  0.14297294,  0.14297294])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple slicing would do

`probs = clf.predict_proba(X)[:, 0] #0 in your case since you need the first one`

Comment: I have 15091 samples. Why I need just the first one?

Comment: prior to your update you needed the first column of predictions. So slice would give you the first column of predictions.

Comment: 15k are your rows. I was saying take the first column only.